# Как отображать список команд при наборе сообщения для бота Telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot

Как добавить в функциональность бота, чтобы при в вводе сообщения отображался выпадающий список команд? 
Использую telebot.

[image: пример списка команд]

Answer (score 1):

Список команд задаётся в настройках ботового аккаунта у [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). Для этого отправьте ему команду `/setcommands`, затем выберите *вашего* бота и введите новый список в таком формате (без слэшей в начале).

```
команда1 - описание
команда2 - ещё описание
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь! Помогло